# Export data from CSV to sql server using asp.net C# TextFieldParser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on exporting CSV to SQL server but it doesn't export anything. I have following code:

```
 protected void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    DataTable tblReadCSV = new DataTable();

    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("IP");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("activityStart");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("activityEnd");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("RCPTcommands");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("DataCommands");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("MessageRecipients");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("FilterResultColor");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("complaintRate");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("trapStart");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("trapEnd");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("trapHits");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("sampleHelo");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("sampleMailFrom");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("comments");
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("URL");

    string path = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/" + path));

    path = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/" + path);
    TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path);
    csvParser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
    csvParser.ReadLine();

    while (!(csvParser.EndOfData == true))
    {
        tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(csvParser.ReadFields());
    }
    string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conMailMonitor"].ConnectionString;

    string strSql = "INSERT INTO tblSnds(IP,activityStart,activityEnd,RCPTcommands,DataCommands,MessageRecipients,FilterResultColor,complaintRate,trapStart,trapEnd,trapHits,sampleHelo,sampleMailFrom,comments,URL)VALUES(@IP,@activityStart,@activityEnd,@RCPTcommands,@DataCommands,@MessageRecipients,@FilterResultColor,@complaintRate,@trapStart,@trapEnd,@trapHits,@sampleHelo,@sampleMailFrom,@comments,@URL)";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strSql;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "IP");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@activityStart", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "activityStart");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@activityEnd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "activityEnd");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RCPTcommands", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "RCPTcommands");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DataCommands", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DataCommands");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageRecipients", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "MessageRecipients");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FilterResultColor", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "FilterResultColor");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@complaintRate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "complaintRate");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@trapStart", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "trapStart");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@trapEnd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "trapEnd");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@trapHits", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "trapHits");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sampleHelo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "activityEnd");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sampleMailFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "sampleMailFrom");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@comments", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "comments");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@URL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "URL");

    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
    int result = dAdapter.Update(tblReadCSV);
    Label1.Text = "File successfully uploaded";
}
```

Contents of CSV are:

```
216.211.128.7,8/12/2013 8:00 AM,8/13/2013 8:00 AM,6610,5642,5644,GREEN,< 0.1%,8/12/2013 11:23 AM,8/12/2013 11:36 AM,4,mail2.adhost.com,bpsupport@betterphoto.com,
```

When I debug, I see that control doesnt go inside the while loop

**while (!(csvParser.EndOfData == true))**

Please suggest how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`MyReader.ReadFields()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readfields.aspx) to advance the reader to the next line:

```
//    csvParser.ReadLine();  <-- remove this
while (!csvParser.EndOfData) {
     string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
     tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(fields);
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readfields.aspx):

> Reads all fields on the current line, returns them as an array of
>   strings, and **advances the cursor to the next line** containing data.

The problem was that you are using `ReadLine` first which skips the first line.